# HighStock Area Charts - Add Two Series

Tags: charts, highcharts

In this example we have two series:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic

but I wish to plot two series on this, the stock type chart:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/area

Any idea if this can be achieved and how?

Comment: Did you even try adding a second series to the stock type chart? http://jsfiddle.net/kBc2W/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoudl use two series:
http://jsfiddle.net/ughPE/

```
    series : [{
                name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data : [[1146441600000,6],
[1146528000000,5],
[1146614400000,10],
[1146700800000,7],
[1146787200000,12],
[1147046400000,8],
[1147132800000,9]],
                type : 'area'
            },{
                name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data : [
[1146787200000,22],
[1147046400000,18],
[1147132800000,1]],
                type : 'area'
            }]
```

Comment: i updated jsfiddle when i add two different series in to chart, only first one displayed on navigator panel. refer http://jsfiddle.net/ughPE/20/